# How to use Massive.cs's .Paged() query with table joins?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, massive

I'm using [Massive, by Rob Conery](https://github.com/robconery/massive), as my "DAL". I've built a repository class using it. I've run into a small problem. I'd like to use the .Paged() method to build paging into one of my ASP.NET MVC views.

Right now, without paging, I'm using .Query()

```
return docTbl.Query("SELECT DISTINCT BaseDocs.* FROM BaseDocs
                     INNER JOIN DocCats ON BaseDocs.DocId = DocCats.DocId
                     WHERE DocCats.CatId IN (1,2,3,4) AND BaseDocs.BaseId = @0
                     ORDER BY BaseDocs.DateUpdated DESC", baseId);
```

I'd like to have this paged, using the .Paged() method, here I use it (not on a joined table)

```
return docTbl.Paged(where: "BaseId = @0", orderby: "DateUpdated DESC",
                    currentPage: currentPage, pageSize: pageSize, args: baseId );
```

Judging by reviewing the .Paged() code in Massive.cs, this may not be possible. Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Currently as it exists no. You could try overloading the paged method to take raw sql.

Comment: Yea, I was afraid someone would say that... guess I'll override it. :)

Comment: you could put in a request to Rob on the git repo.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the comment "reminder" on this question. I've created my own .Paged() method called .PagedJoin(). Thanks though!

Comment: One of these comments should probably be an accepted answer. That will keep this question from showing up as an unanswered SQL question. @msarchet should probably rewrite as an answer.